# Shape inheritance in SVG

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, inkscape

Is there a concept of shape inheritance in SVG?

Problem:
I'm creating a map with various icon types that represent different entities on the map. Is there a way to link these icon types, so that I can modify the "parent" (say the icon in a legend) and all the "children" will inherit those properties?

Doing it in Inkscape, but I'm hoping it's an SVG property, and thus a valid Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "properties".

You can use CSS `class="foo"` to apply visual styling to your elements, e.g. `fill:red; stroke-width:2px`. Changing the CSS rule will affect the visual style of all shapes with that class.

However, perhaps what you want is the [`<use>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) element, which allows you to have many lightweight references to a single shape (or arbitrary set of geometry) placed throughout your document. Changes to the original shapes/paths/visual styles affect all instances.

A `<use>` element may reference a specific shape, a `<g>`roup of shapes, or even an entire `<svg>` document.

To create a special source graphic that is not displayed on its own you can either use a [`<symbol>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SymbolElement) (which has a `viewBox`), or place any content in the  [`<defs>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Head) section (such as a `<g>`).

Here is an example showing the use of symbols and `<use>` to place identical markers on a map:
http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/symbol.shtml

Comment: It even works in Inkscape! I manually added a <use xlink:href="#xxx"/> tag and the properties of that child are now inherited from the parent. Thanks again!